# AjaxTabcontainer is not rendered properly from 2 days on server

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

My site www.byohbaraat.com/index is having issue in tab container control which are not rendered properly and the visibility seems to be hidden.Its is from last 2 days otherwise on server it was working fine.
I have now made visibility:visible but still the tab panel captcha and tabs not working as expected.My second tab container is in right side panel for Post an ad which is also displaying in the footer part.
Please provide me solution if any.
http://prntscr.com/8581nu

Answer (score 0):

You start by opening the debugs tools of your browser and start looking for errors on javascript and what is not loaded...

For example I just see that some files not loaded at all, and you have many javascript errors...

So you can take from here and move on to fix this errors - all reds are errors...

[image: Not loaded]

[image: Errors]

Comment: How can I solve error for ScriptResource.axd? can you please help here

Comment: @inventorstech I can not because I do not know what the real error is... solve all errors one by one, and then look on the internet for the last one.